# Volume of a rectangular prism after t days

Tags: derivatives, volume

I'm really stuck on this question and would like some direction.

An iceberg approximates the shape of a rectangular prism and is about 800 m long, 400 m wide and 120 m thick. As it moves into warmer water it melts evenly by 1 m per day along each measurement.

Find the volume of the iceberg after 't' days

The answer in the textbook states:

$$V(t) = 38 400 000 − 464 000t + 1320t^2 − t^3$$

Any suggestion would be great

Comment: I’m sure that you’ll be able to tell us your thoughts about the question.

Comment: $V=(800-t)(400-t)(120-t)$

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net I was initally thinking could this be a related rates question, but it doesn't seem to work out. I then tried using simultaneous equations using volume and the surface area formula but then again I don't think that is the right direction

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan wow I do not understand how I did not think like that, thank you so much!

Comment: @user415903 At least tell us what is the volume of a rectangular prism knowing its dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Trying this question from the basics would be helpful.

The volume of a rectangular prism is the product of the three sides.

The initial sides are $800,400,120$  respectively.

Since each sides reduces by $1$m in one day, after $t$ days there will be a reduction of $t$ meters in each side.

Therefore, the sides of the prism, at  the end of $t$ days, will be $800-t,400-t,120-t$. Therefore the volume will be the product of these three i.e. $(800-t)(400-t)(120-t)$. Expanding the products leads to the given answer.